# Subtracting from an initial percentage but only when user inputs "no"/false C#

Tags: c#, string

in my code the issue that follow is , I have a few if statements requiring user input . And I would like to set a number (100) that if a user input == no , then x number deducts from 100 but I need it so say the first user to say no , (100-y)=a and then the second user to say no , his value would deduct a-y let's say.

The counters are being used for something else . I am kinda new to C# , hope it makes sense all the help appreciated.

```
namespace Ice_Cream
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            int counter2 = 0;
            int counter3 = 0;
            int PercentageDisklikes = 100;

            string[] Foods = { "Icecream" , "Coffee" , "Sweetpotato" };
            string[] Dislike = { "5", "10", "3" };
            Console.WriteLine(Foods[0]);
            string Icecream = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Do you like Ice cream? " );

            if (Icecream == "yes")
            {
                counter++;
                Console.WriteLine("Amount of ppl that like Ice cream: " + counter);




            }
            if (Icecream == "no")
            {
                counter2++;
                Console.WriteLine("Amount of ppl that don't like Ice cream " + counter2);
                Console.WriteLine("Study shows 10% of people agree with you");
                // Here i would like int PercentageDisklikes = 100 - 5 to then
                //Console.WriteLine("Ovr satisfaction (= 100 -5)
            }
            else if (Icecream == "maybe")
            {
                counter2++;
                counter3++;
                Console.WriteLine("Amount of ppl that don't like Ice cream : " + counter2);
                Console.WriteLine("Amount of ppl that maybe don't like Ice cream: " + counter3);
                // Here i would like int PercentageDisklikes = 100 - 5 to then
                //Console.WriteLine("Ovr satisfaction (= 100 -5)
            }

            Console.WriteLine(Foods[1]);
            string Coffee = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Do you like Coffee? ");

            if (Coffee == "yes")
            {
                counter++;
                Console.WriteLine("Amount of ppl that like Coffee: " + counter);




            }
            if (Coffee == "no")
            {
                counter2++;
                Console.WriteLine("Amount of ppl that don't like Coffee " + counter2);
                Console.WriteLine("Study shows 10% of people agree with you");
                // Here i would like int PercentageDisklikes = 95 - 5 to then (95 from previous result)
                //Console.WriteLine("Ovr satisfaction (= 95 -5)
            }
            else if (Coffee== "maybe")
            {
                counter2++;
                counter3++;
                Console.WriteLine("Amount of ppl that don't like Coffee : " + counter2);
                Console.WriteLine("Amount of ppl that maybe don't like Coffee : " + counter3);
                // Here i would like int PercentageDisklikes = 95 - 5 to then
                //Console.WriteLine("Ovr satisfaction" + PercentageDislikes (= 95 -5)
            }
```

Comment: Can't understand your question

Comment: post your tried code, the code that you posted seems like not your tried code

Comment: ` then x number deducts from 100 but I need it so say the first user to say no , (100-y)=a `  where is `y` coming from ?

Comment: C# or not, all you have access to is loops and branches (if, switch statements), there are more degrees of freedom in Lego. So when you debug this and step through the code, do you have an idea of what is not working for you? And *debug* is the keyword here

Comment: Really unclear. Manythings a weird in this code. The variable name. Some assignation eguality `(Ice cream == "maybe")` . Semi colon missing , semi colon miss placed `+ counter;)`. I will recommend taking 3 minute to read [ask]. Then clarify your question. Making simple sentence to explain the context.

Comment: Why are you removing from a percentage instead of simply counting yes/no/maybe per product?

Comment: First of all, do not name variables like: Counter1, counter2, counter3, instead name them like: coffeeCounter,iceCounter, whatever that would say us exactly what each counter is for. What is more, you should follow what @DragandDrop said. Your question is so unclear, i can barelly understand what you want to achieve, is it your code in some loop ? Where counters are declarated? Maybe it would be easier if you would use the same counter for example for coffee likers and dislikers, you wouldnt do any maths then. Have in mind that you can also do something like: counter--;

Comment: @DragandDrop in my assignment I need something similar to this but it includes %s - this is an example

Answer (score 0):

```
 int counter = 0;
        int counter2 = 0;
        int counter3 = 0;
        string[] Foods = { "Icecream", "Coffee", "Sweetpotato" };
        string[] Dislike = { "5", "10", "3" };

        int PercentageDisklikes = 100;
        int subNumber = 5;

        Console.WriteLine(Foods[0]);
        string Icecream = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Do you like Ice cream? ");

        if (Icecream == "yes")
        {
            counter++;
            Console.WriteLine("Amount of ppl that like Ice cream: " + counter);

        }
        else if (Icecream == "no")
        {
            counter2++;
            Console.WriteLine("Amount of ppl that don't like Ice cream " + counter2);
            Console.WriteLine("Study shows 10% of people agree with you");
            PercentageDisklikes = PercentageDisklikes - subNumber;
            Console.WriteLine($"Our satisfaction = {PercentageDisklikes}%");
        }
        else if (Icecream == "maybe")
        {
            counter2++;
            counter3++;
            Console.WriteLine("Amount of ppl that don't like Ice cream : " + counter2);
            Console.WriteLine("Amount of ppl that maybe don't like Ice cream: " + counter3);
            PercentageDisklikes = PercentageDisklikes - subNumber;
            Console.WriteLine($"Our satisfaction = {PercentageDisklikes}%");
        }

        //Here you must reset the counters, or you mix
        //Icecream and Coffe people

        counter = 0;
        counter2 = 0;
        counter3 = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(Foods[1]);
        string Coffee = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Do you like Coffee? ");

        if (Coffee == "yes")
        {
            counter++;
            Console.WriteLine("Amount of ppl that like Coffee: " + counter);


        }
        if (Coffee == "no")
        {
            counter2++;
            Console.WriteLine("Amount of ppl that don't like Coffee " + counter2);
            Console.WriteLine("Study shows 10% of people agree with you");
            PercentageDisklikes = PercentageDisklikes - subNumber;
            Console.WriteLine($"Our satisfaction = {PercentageDisklikes}%");
        }
        else if (Coffee == "maybe")
        {
            counter2++;
            counter3++;
            Console.WriteLine("Amount of ppl that don't like Coffee : " + counter2);
            Console.WriteLine("Amount of ppl that maybe don't like Coffee : " + counter3);
            PercentageDisklikes = PercentageDisklikes - subNumber;
            Console.WriteLine($"Our satisfaction = {PercentageDisklikes}%");
        }
```

I also don't understand what exactly you want. If you have more questions ask. I'm new to C# too and I can tell you that it is not Python language :-)

[Read this tutorial, will cost you exactly one day.](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it in the following manner. Count the number of times you ask the question. Count the responses to each question. Display the results.

```
        double numberAsked = 0;
        double yesIcecream = 0, noIcecream = 0, maybeIcecream = 0;
        while (true) // have a nice way to exit in your app
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do you like Ice cream? ");
            string answer = Console.ReadLine();
            numberAsked++;
            if (answer == "yes")
            {
                yesIcecream++;
            }
            else if (answer == "no")
            {
                noIcecream++;
            }
            else if (answer == "maybe")
            {
                maybeIcecream++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"yes: { yesIcecream / numberAsked * 100}%");
            Console.WriteLine($"no: { noIcecream / numberAsked * 100 }%");
            Console.Write($"maybe: { maybeIcecream / numberAsked * 100 }%\n\n");
        }
```